# Show that the equation $a(t)v_x(x,t)+b(x)v_x(x,t)=0$ has the general solution $v(x,t)=F[B(x)-A(t)]$ where $B^\prime(x)=b(x)$ and $A^\prime(t)=a(t)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that the equation $a(t)v_x(x,t)+b(x)v_t(x,t)=0$ has the general solution $v(x,t)=F[B(x)-A(t)]$ where $B^\prime(x)=b(x)$ and $A^\prime(t)=a(t)$.

This problem is similar to a homework problem I'm struggling with. I started the other problem, but I'm not sure if I started it right.  So if someone could show me how to do this, that would be good.

I'm working out of "PDEs of Applied Mathematics" by Zauderer, if that helps. Section 2.2.

Comment: Is F a function or a constant?

Comment: I think I'm supposed to assume $v(x,0)=F(x)$ or something, but I'm completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this problem.

1) Solve by method of characteristics

2) Use the solution to find the criterion for the argument to be the correct choice. This goes as follows
Set $z = B(x) - A(t)$ we then transform the original derivatives in terms of z
$$
v_{x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}.\\
v_{y} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}
$$
insert into the original pde to yield
$$
a(t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + b(x)\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0.
$$
Factoring out $\partial F/\partial z$ the above leads to 
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\left[a(t)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+b(x)\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right] = 0,
$$
Now compute the partials for z.
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\left[a(t)B^{'}(x)+b(x)\left(-A^{'}(t)\right)\right] = 0,
$$

so we have the condition that 
$$
a(t)B^{'}(x)-b(x)A^{'}(t) = 0
$$
Which clearly implies that 
$$
B^{'}(x) = b(x),\\
A^{'}(t) = a(t).
$$
Hope this helps.